# Same motion verb, subject, object and preposition for accusative and dative - Possible?

Tags: grammatical-case

Which one is correct? or both correct?

> Ich gehe in den Markt
>
> I go to the market

or

> Ich gehe im Markt  -
>   I go inside the market

Comment: You will notice how people assume *der Markt* being a building in your example. That is because open places require the preposition *auf* rather than *in*.

Comment: Thanks, could you please give the links of pages that provide distinction between these prepositions.

Comment: https://coerll.utexas.edu/gg/gr/cas_09.html

Comment: Very useful link,Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct.

- **Accusative** = move to a target, into a direction.

  > Ich fahre in die Schweiz.
  >   I drive to Switzerland.

  This means: I am outside of Switzerland and I am going to cross the border to Switzerland.
- **Dative** = move on a spot, inside an area.

  > Ich fahre in der Schweiz.
  >   I drive in Switzerland.

  This means: I am inside of Switzerland and I am not going to cross any border. I am driving around, but I will not leave Switzerland.

And so:

- **Accusative** = target, direction

  > Ich gehe in den Markt.
  >   I go to the market.
- **Dative** = spot, area

  > Ich gehe in dem Markt. = Ich gehe im Markt.
  >   I walk inside the market.

Comment: Does it mean, the more appropriate English translation for the dative is, 'walk inside' rather than,'go inside'?

Comment: You could mention that this only works for a small fixed set of prepositions.

Comment: Could you please elaborate